# Mura site getting error "Variable RS undefined". Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Tags: coldfusion, mura

The site has not been updated for maybe 9 yrs. Now when I login as Admin to get to the Update link, it won't even load that due to this error. So I am unable to update to possibly fix this error due to the error blocking even that.

Any ideas short of hacking the code to get a workaround? Given the content in the site I'm not wanting to reinstall it, unless it can be done without loss.

The location of the error is on line 58 of:

```
...\wwwroot\requirements\mura\settings\settingsGateway.cfc
```

Comment: Have you tried reloading the Mura application via the URL key (by default it is `appreload` but you should have changed that)? Might also help to know which version of Mura you are on?  Which flavor of ColdFusion (Adobe or Lucee)?  Which version of ColdFusion?

Comment: Yes. It sounds like a simple 'appreload' job. The Application cache probably expired a long time ago, so it probably needs reloading. If it is a dev version, then you might be OK with 'appreload'...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved. I was on version 5 of Mura and ColdFusion 11 on the server-side. It turns out the hosting service had applied a new CF patch from Adobe which broke Mura sites that use the cachedwithin perimeter. The workaround was to remove cachedwithin usage. But the server host just informed me that Adobe has issued another patch which takes care of the original problem so everything is back to normal.